# chi square goodness of degrees of freedom issue

Tags: python, statistics

I am trying to do a goodness of fit test and the ddof is 0 as per default but I have 3 categories (k=2). When I specify the ddof=2, the p value gives nan. However the chi test statistic is correct.

```
observed=[50,41,85]
expected=[44,33,99]
chisq, p = st.chisquare(observed,expected)

print(f'X2={chisq:.2f},p={p:.2f}')

X2=4.74,p=0.09

chisquare(observed,expected,ddof=[0,1,2])


Power_divergenceResult(statistic=4.737373737373738, pvalue=array([0.09360356, 0.02951409,        nan]))
```

Why is the p value giving nan for ddof=2 and why is the test taking ddof as 0 instead of 2? There are 3 categories. Shouldn't the ddof be 2 for this case?

Comment: why is the p value giving nan for ddof =2 and why is the test taking ddof as 0 instead of 2. There are 3 categories. shouldnt the ddof be 2 for this case ?